# Can I store @mixin in any other file(_file.scss) or I can only store it in the main file?

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm new to sass and want to know that can I store **@mixin** in a file other than **main.scss** because it makes the main file a little to messy like CSS, If it can work then how can I proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Create a new .scss file and import it into your main.scss file using [@import](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/import)

e.g. https://codesandbox.io/s/mixin-zu97i

Comment: that's very helpful and simple.
one more thing, Is it necessary to import the mixin to the main file, or else I can use the HTML elements to style in this new mixin.scss file

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed like you suspected place your mixins in another file and refer to it.

For example you could do the following.

```
Structure:
main.scss
_functions.scss
```

Inside `_functions.scss`

```
@mixin transform($property) {
  -webkit-transform: $property;
  -ms-transform: $property;
  transform: $property;
}
// [+ other mixins]
```

Inside `main.scss`

```
/* Place this on the first line of your main file */
import "_functions";

.box { 
    @include transform(rotate(30deg)); 
}

/* [The rest of your SASS] */
```

Why did I use a underscore(_)? This way the SASS/Compiler knows that this file is a partial, what is a partial?

> A partial is a Sass file named with a leading underscore. You might
>   name it something like _partial.scss. The underscore lets Sass know
>   that the file is only a partial file and that it should not be
>   generated into a CSS file. Sass partials are used with the @use rule.

Source (would recommend reading/scanning through it):
https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-4

Comment: I think that (_) is not necessary when you are importing the file. It is only recommended to use when you are saving the some _new.scss file.
I just watched it in the tutorial, If I am wrong please let me know.